# db connection uses an anonymous logon instead of the domain user

Tags: sql-server, php

I have this PHP code running under IIS:

```
$serverName = "someServer\someServer";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"SOME_DB");

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

When I try to visit the page, I get the error:

> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

Which is confusing, as the [documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) says "The connection will be attempted using Windows Authentication".

The flow of this is:

1. User using `x` Windows account on `workstation1` visits this website hosted on `server1`
2. `server1` executes above PHP code and tries to retrieve data from `server2` using `y` Windows account (`y` is defined in the IIS settings, under Application Pools->Identity)
3. Windows account `y` has access to the database

The IIS pool is running under a Windows domain user "domainadm" which has access to the `SOME_DB` database and the server it sits on.

Why is it trying to authenticate anonymously and how can I fix this so it runs under the user the IIS pool is running as?

In php.ini:

```
fastcgi.impersonate = 1;
```

Checking the Authentication section in IIS, the only options I have are "Anonymous Authentication" or "ASP.NET Impersonation". No Windows authentication?

Anonymous is currently enabled, which gives the error above. If I switch to the ASP.NET one I instead get this error when visiting the page:

> 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: Is Windows Authentication enabled in IIS?

Comment: @JohnMcCall Apparently not. My only options are "Anonymous Authentication" or "ASP.NET Impersonation"

Comment: In the Authentication section, what is it currently set to? Have you tried "ASP.NET Impersonation"?

Comment: I tried the ASP.NET one, got a different error. See OP

Comment: Is your php.ini file using fastcgi.impersonate = 1?

Comment: @Jeremy Yes, just checked and it's 1

Comment: How is anonymous authentication configured in IIS?
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770966(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Reading [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php) I found something relevant:

> For example IIS 7, in its default configuration, has anonymous
>   authentication enabled with built-in user account IUSR used as a
>   default identity. This means that in order for IIS to execute PHP
>   scripts, it is necessary to grant IUSR account read permission on
>   those scripts. If PHP applications need to perform write operations on
>   certain files or write files into some folders then IUSR account
>   should have write permission to those.

And [iis.net](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis) has the following relevant information:

> This built-in account does not need a password and will be the default
>   identity that is used when anonymous authentication is enabled. If you
>   look in the applicationHost.config file you will see the following
>   definition:
>
> `<anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" userName="IUSR" defaultLogonDomain="" />`
>
> This tells IIS to use the new built-in
>   account for all anonymous authentication requests.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Could this be a double-hop delegation problem since apparently Kerberos is not being used?  Every machine in the chain, from the workstation to the database needs to use Kerberos authentication.

You mention visiting the page, which then queries the database. Which could be interpreted as a double-hop, although I do not fully understand the topology from the description.

I interpreted the topology as: Workstation / IIS Server / SQL Server.

The following post explains the technology: [Double-hop authentication: Why NTLM fails and Kerberos works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/besidethepoint/double-hop-authentication-why-ntlm-fails-and-kerberos-works).

Basically, NTLM is not able to go through the middle server to the next server because it does not have the password hash for NTLM to work with moving forward.

Using Kerberos authentication does not require access to the password hash, using instead the session ticket to define itself.

Comment: I don't think so. I edited my post, sorry I think it was confusing. A Windows already is already defined in IIS to connect as, under the App Pool.

Answer (score 0):

"*The IIS pool is running under a Windows domain user "domainadm" which has access to the SOME_DB database and the server it sits on.*"

can you check if the user that you are trying to authenticate has been added to the security group on the dB server where your schema is located and the security login for that user is created with serveradmin access.

Comment: Yes, that's already done. That isn't the issue, read the OP. It's trying to connect as anon for some reason.